# Parse APNIC bulk whois data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing bulkwhois data and it is stored in a txt file.  It contains 12,517,501 rows with pretty much the same information repeated over and over again in one column.  All entries start with "inetnum" and end with "source: source name 1".  Most of the information in between has the same information but some of it is out of order, like some of the entries have 3 descriptions and others have 4 descriptions.  Another thing is for example is the first entry "admin-c: admin 1" comes after "descr: description 1" but in the second entry "admin-c: admin 2" comes after "country: country name 2".  The df is a single column.  The following is the first two entries:

```
data
inetnum: ip range 1
netname: net name 1
country: country name 1
descr: description 1
descr: description 1
descr: description 1
admin-c: admin 1
tech-c: tech 1
status: status 1
mnt-by: mnt-by 1
mnt-routes: mnt-routes 1
last-modified: last modified 1
source: source name 1
inetnum: ip range 2
netname: net name 2
descr: description 2
descr: description 2
descr: description 2
country: country name 2
admin-c: admin 2
tech-c: tech 2
mnt-by: mnt-by 2
remarks: remarks 2
status: status 2
last-modified: last modified 2
source: source name 1
```

My desire out put would for each entry anything that starts with "inetum:" and ends with "source: source name 1" these always stay the same, in this format:

```
inetnum    netname     ...  source
ip range 1 net name 1  ...  source name 1
ip range 2  net name 2  ...  source name 1
```

I was thinking if I seperate the one column into two like:

```
apnic2entry2 = pd.DataFrame(apnic2entry.data.str.split(':',1).tolist(),
                       columns = ['field', 'data'])
```

This gives me a field and data column:

```
field    data    
inetnum  ip range 1
netname  net name 1
country  country name 1
...      ...
```

Then maybe do a transpose and match the data column to the fields.

How do I get this output?

```
inetnum    netname     ...  source
ip range 1 net name 1  ...  source name 1
ip range 2  net name 2  ...  source name 1
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the multiple desc fields create a list?

Comment: Include them with all of the other data if possible @Scott Boston

Comment: So you need a desc_1, desc_2, desc_3 column?

Comment: I would prefer that due to the additional data it provides @ScottBoston

Comment: Just as a note this data is scrubbed due to not being allowed to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this.

```
df_out = df['data'].str.split(': ', expand=True)
df_out = df_out.set_index([0,(df_out[0] == 'inetnum').cumsum().rename('row')])
df_out = df_out.set_index(df_out.groupby([0,'row']).cumcount(), append=True)
df_out = df_out.reset_index('row')
df_out.index = df_out.index.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df_out = df_out.set_index(['row'], append=True)[1].unstack(0)
df_out = df_out.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('_0')[0]).reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   row  admin-c         country          descr        descr_1        descr_2     inetnum    last-modified    mnt-by    mnt-routes     netname    remarks         source    status  tech-c
0    1  admin 1  country name 1  description 1  description 1  description 1  ip range 1  last modified 1  mnt-by 1  mnt-routes 1  net name 1        NaN  source name 1  status 1  tech 1
1    2  admin 2  country name 2  description 2  description 2  description 2  ip range 2  last modified 2  mnt-by 2           NaN  net name 2  remarks 2  source name 1  status 2  tech 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, very slick!  Thank you @Scott Boston